# Как нарисовать обратный треугольник звездочками с помощью циклов?

Tags: javascript

С помощью вложенных циклов и символа * надо нарисовать треугольник с вершиной внизу, вот так:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Как это сделать в вложенном цикле?

---

Я пробовал так:

```js
let out = document.querySelector("#out")
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(let k = 5; k > 0; k--){
        out.innerHTML += "*"
    }
    out.innerHTML += `<br>`
}
```

```html
<div id=out></div>
```

но у меня выводится так:

```
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

Comment: А что у вас не получается конкретно?

Comment: первый цикл по строке i от 0 до 4, второй цикл по символам в строке от 5-i до 1. внутри второго цикла выводим *, после первого цикла делаем возврат карретки. про циклы в js можно прочитать [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Comment: У меня не получается уменьшить длину. Они просо повторяются "*****" и так 5 раз.

Comment: Приложите код...

Comment: Алексей, приложил код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Основной смысл в том, чтобы уменьшать начальное значение `k` с каждым разом на то число, на которое увеличивается `i`. То есть каждый раз нужно, чтобы `k` начиналось не с 5, а уменьшалось: сначала с 5, потом с 4 потом с 3 потом с 2 и т.д.

```js
let out = document.querySelector("#out")
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(let k = 5 - i; k > 0; k--){
            //  ^^^^^
        out.innerHTML += "*"
    }
    out.innerHTML += `<br>`
}
```

```html
<div id=out></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый нормальный способ - это ограничиться одной записью в dom:

```js
function build(n) {
  var res = ""

  for(let q = 0; q < n; ++q){
    res += "*".repeat(n - q) + "\n"
  }
  
  return res
}

document.querySelector("#out").textContent = build(5)
```

```css
#out {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id=out></div>
```

Comment: Странно, что это пишешь ты, а не измерятель асимптотики))

Comment: По поводу твоего коммента в удалённом сообщении (мы, смертные, не можем писать там комменты и ответить) - я не писал про четыре вложенных цикла. Я писал просто про 4 цикла :-)  Вот в целом, там получалось их очень много :-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, но не вложенные циклы асимптотику не портят. К тому же, лучше квадратичной ей всё равно не быть, потому что картинка-то квадратичная. Ну и операции с dom'ом жрут куда больше времени, чем циклы по массивам.

Comment: да, но там был вложенный цикл как у меня **и плюс ещё**. Так что явно это всё портило и не сходилось с мыслью автора)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, так у вас у обоих плюс во вложенном цикле, причём не просто сложение строк, которое оптимизиуреутся, а html, который после каждого прибавления будет полностью заново парситься как разметка и пересоздавать dom-дерево.

Comment: Да я знаю. Но суть-то была в том, что чел рассказывает про асимптотики, про избегание вложенных циклов, а у самого нагроможждение было.....я не писал "оптимизированно", потому что задача не в этом заключалась.....а вот при различного рода утверждениях надо бы подтверждать слова, но при этом автор удосужился написать ещё более  неэффективное решение, не смог соблюсти свои же асимптотики и правила и сделал ещё хуже

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а вообще, я сейчас посмотрел - его решение было более эффективным потому что запись в dom только по количеству строк.